# Require/include in PHP frameworks

Tags: php, include, slim

I just started refactoring my non-framework project into using Slim and Twig to try and make it follow a more modern design pattern.

I've come to the conclusion already, that for each route I have on my site, I will have to have a corresponding require with a matching path - or a require that has all possible paths in one (I don't know if there's a noticeable difference there aside from the logical separation of code).

It does not make sense in my head to include possibly (in my case) 80-100 routes and try and match them for **every single request** when the request could determine where we wanted to go in the first place - assuming we went away from the single-point-of-entry philosophy that Slim and so many other frameworks build upon. Is this how it's supposed to work or is there something I have misunderstood?  I have read numerous tutorials on many different frameworks in attempt to find the right one for my project (which in itself was and still is a nightmare), and none of them seem to touch on the subject of "Hey - why are we doing this so inefficiently?"

Is the include/require operation simply so fast that we should not care, and we just sacrifice this for manageability? Excuse my ignorance, but when coming from a project where I only type require/include when I actually need something, this seems, well, stupid. I should mention that that development style has turned my project into chaos, which is why I've ended up here with Slim in the first place.

I just want to understand if I'm doing it right.

Comment: Why would you need a require for each route? All you would need to require in your `index.php` is the the `autoloader.php` from the vendor folder.

Comment: As @DavidDomain pointed out, what you are actually missing here is that those framework do not include anything that do not need to be used. They just have those kind if dictionary listing what class they should include for each route and then they include it on the fly with `autoloaders` (see : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: I am requiring the autoloader, but also a file that contains each route.
I've built upon the example here: https://youtu.be/Lgcat0WkuE0?t=501 where we have a file called routes.php that includes all our possible routes. Is that not a good solution? Edit: Changed to better example.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, you want a separate php file for each route? I have yet to see a project that needed so many unique routes, couldn't some of the routes have abstractions in the form of URL params, that kind of thing?

Comment: @nickdnk take a look at the following tutorial to get a better idea on how to bootstrap your application and loading components. 

       https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/php-bootstrapping-crash-course/146

Comment: I think I confused routes with routes+methods, meaning there are a lot less actual routes in my project. I haven't really begun yet as I'm still trying to wrap my head around this concept. My project is pretty big already, so the rewrite is going to take a lot of time. I will read your link, David. Thanks.

Comment: I read your tutorial, David, but it only explains what I already know: I must explicitly define each possible route in my entire app. There is no clever autoloading when it comes to testing the path.